Flutter Plugin for Android not finding the "io" import (Kolin file highlighting broken) Android Studio
I'm trying to develop a android flutter plugin. The problem im encountering is that i cant't find a way to open up the android file that provides propper highlighting. The code in Kotlin works fine when executet, but Android Studio marks it as false.
I would love to get propper suggestions and highlighting from Android Studio while editing the kotlin file so I know what I'm doing. What seams to be missing are the references to the dart features on the native side.
What I've tried:

Opening the android module part of the plugin seperatly
Opening the example module part of the plugin seperatly
Opening the example/android module part of the plugin seperatly
Trying diffrent versions of Android Studio


I was also wondering this, take a look at the docs:
https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#step-2b-add-android-platform-code-kt-java
You need to build the example app at least once and then don't open the android folder directly but rather open the example application.
